# Ruby: Strange method declaration

Tags: ruby, rest

I am new to ruby (coming from java), but as i know a method declarations should begin with `_def method name do ..... end`.

I am trying to use a framework for REST api client programming. (weary)

My question is: Why is it possible to declare a method like below?  Why is not '_def', used?

For me it looks like a mixture between an attribute and method, I am confused.

```
class MyClass < Weary::Client


    # List content by folder
    get :get_my_rest_api_folder, "/abc/my/rest/api/folder/{parentid}" do |resource|
        resource.required :parentid 
end
```

Comment: ...actually it's `def` not `_def` and there should be no `do` after `method_name`...

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not a method declaration, it's a method call with a block attached to it. This is basically the same:

```
@@GET_MY_REST_API_FOLDER = "get_my_rest_api_folder"
get(GET_MY_REST_API_FOLDER, "/abc...") do |resource|
  ...
end
```

The code inside the block will be executed in the scope of the target object.

Answer (score 0):

You're not declaring a method, you're calling a method called `get`.  That method may be in turn declaring a method for you in your class.

Methods can be invoked in what seems like "un-executable" space in your class, if you're used to other C-like languages.